Does nice behavior near a singular point force solution to be in Frobenius series?
I have a pair of partial differential operators $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ in $y_1, y_2$ formed from constants, multiplication by $y_1$ or $y_2$ and derivatives in the form $y_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}$, $y_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y_2}$.  I know that there are exactly 12 Frobenius series solutions $\Delta_1 f_j = \Delta_2 f_j=0$,
$$ f_j(y_1,y_2) = y_1^{i a_{j,1}} y_2^{i a_{j,2}} \sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \sum_{n_2=0}^\infty b_{j,n_1,n_2} y_1^{n_1} y_2^{n_2}, \qquad j=1,\ldots,12 $$
with $a_{j,k} \in \mathbb{R}$, $b_{j,n_1,n_2} \in \mathbb{C}$, $b_{j,0,0}=1$.
I have another function $g(y_1,y_2)$, defined by an integral which also satisfies $\Delta_1 g = \Delta_2 g = 0$ and near the singular point $y_1=y_2=0$ has
$$ g(y_1,y_2) = \sum_{j=1}^{12} c_j y_1^{i a_{j,1}} y_2^{i a_{j,2}}+O(y_1+y_2). $$
If I knew that the space of all solutions has dimension 12, I could conclude that
$$ g(y_1,y_2) = \sum_{j=1}^{12} c_j f_j(y_1, y_2). $$
I cannot show the dimension is 12; it may well be false.
Is this condition on the behavior of $g$ near the singular point enough to conclude it lies in the span of the Frobenius series?
Something to the effect of solutions that don't lie in the span of the Frobenius series must be badly behaved near the singular point?
